# How enable iPhone  camera buttons (zoom , flash , switch)

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk

I am trying to use  camera for my application but the problem is when I use this code the front camera is disable :

```
 ipc.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
```

and vice versa !

```
  ipc.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
```

how can i enable both them together ?  I mean ENABLE the switch button to use front and rear camera , !!! all the buttons are disable ! Zoom , Flash , camera switch

CODE :

```
-(IBAction)takePic {


    USImage.hidden = YES;
    ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];

    ipc.delegate = self;
    ipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera; 



    ipc.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
    ipc.cameraViewTransform = YES;

    [self presentModalViewController:ipc animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this code and it lets me switch the camera perfectly fine:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
[imagePicker release];
```

Comment: thanks but did not work !!! all the buttons are disable ! Zoom , Flash , camera switch

Comment: Then you didn't use exactly my code, the one I posted enables everything

Comment: I figured it out ! that was because my `cameraOverlayView`

Comment: Ah, good to know :) Never used that feature so far, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

you can't use them at the same time

Comment: No I mean ENABLE the switch button  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just don't provide neither of both lines ;). If you don't set up cameraDevice, the button will be presented (and working like charm) on your ImagePickerController

Comment: `cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto` ? Think this is the error ;).

Comment: i removed this line but nothing changed !

Comment: I figured it out ! that was because my `cameraOverlayView`